# Google Play restricts the use of the SMS and Call Log permissions

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

If I have an app which is still in the development and not yet published but I am planning to launch it through Google play store. My App is introducing a feature where the user can retrieve his latest SMS and Call logs so the app requires granting the SMS and call log permissions.

- As per the application is not yet published, Am I required to fill
  the google form?
- Are these restrictions applied by google play store itself, not the
  Android OS so if I distributed the app through any other tool other
  than play store it will work normally?

Answer (score 2):

> As per the application is not yet published, Am I required to fill the
>   google form?

You can fill the [google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform) after publish your app on Google Play Store.

**According to Google:**

You should only access Call Log or SMS permissions to enable your app’s core functionality.
Core functionality is the main purpose of the app. It’s the feature most prominently documented and promoted in the app’s description; no other feature is more central to the app’s functionality. If this feature isn’t provided, the app is “broken” (for example, won’t perform as a user would expect).

Please read [Google’s restrictions on SMS/Call Log permissions are forcing some apps to abandon useful features](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-restriction-sms-call-log-permissions/) for more information

> Are these restrictions applied by google play store itself, not the
>   Android OS so if I distributed the app through any other tool other
>   than play store it will work normally?

This restriction only on google play store, you can still distribute the app on others store.